# Adding panels to SplitContainer in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, splitcontainer

I'm having trouble finding the documentation on how to add panels to a [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0w5ctby.aspx). I can create the SplitContainer fine, but I can't put the panels I've coded inside of the splitcontainer.

I've tried doing

```
sc.Container.Add(myPanel);
sc.Container.Add(myOtherPanel);
```

But `Container` is always null. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `SplitContainer` always contains two panels and you cannot change that! (And you don't need to add any panels yourself.)

You can access the two panels through the properties `Panel1` and `Panel2`.

If you need more panels, you can however nest several `SplitContainers`.

---

**UPDATE**

You cannot replace the existing panels. What you can do, is to place your own controls on the existing split container panels (and your controls can also be System.Windows.Forms.Panels containing other controls or user defined controls):

```
sc.Panel1.Controls.Add(myPanel);
sc.Panel2.Controls.Add(myOtherPanel);

myPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
myOtherPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Of course you can add them using the forms designer of Visual Studio of as well, if you don't have a scenario where you have to add controls dynamically. If you create your own controls, they will automatically appear in the Toolbox inside of the same project and you can just drag and drop them on the SplitContainer's panels.

Comment: I'm not trying to add more panels to it. I'm wanting to put the panels I've coded inside of the splitcontainer. I'll edit my post.

Comment: I see. The panels are already created and you just have to add controls to them yourself. Thanks.

Comment: Yes and you can add them using the forms designer of Visual Studio of cause, if you don't have a scenario where you have to add controls dynamically. If you create your own controls, they will automatically appear in the Toolbox inside of the same project and you can just drag and drop them on the SplitContainer's panels.

Answer (score 1):

The SplitContainer control already has two panels named Panel1 and Panel2.  Select the panel you want to use:

```
sc.Panel1.Controls.Add(myPanel);
sc.Panel2.Controls.Add(myOtherPanel);
```