# creating html div in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory, html

I am using the following code to make an html div in c#

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl dynDiv =
        new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            dynDiv.ID = "dynDivCode";
            dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Gray");
            dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "20px");
            dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "300px");
            dynDiv.InnerHtml = "I was created using Code Behind";

            this.Controls.Add(dynDiv);
```

But this doesnot do a thing, infact it gives an error at the last line that dynDiv is not a valid argument.
I want to use div here to simulate cache memory line and placement of words in cache memory.Please tell me how to do it

Comment: In your comments you say you are using WinForms, not ASP. You can't combine HTML or ASP.Net controls with WinForms. You can use a Panel.

Answer (score 4):

You could just embed the html inside a literal control.

```
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div style='color: gray; height: 20px; width: 300px;'>I was created using Code Behind</div>"));
```

Comment: Scartag i have used this code this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("")); but it gives an error, that invalid argument, isthere any namespace required for using this code

Comment: @HanyaIdrees No, there isn't any namespace to add .. LiteralControl is inside System.Web.UI namespace.

Comment: i am coding in C#, not in aspx

Comment: @HanyaIdrees If you are not using asp.net then you won't be working on a codebehind... that's why you are having issues .. in an asp.net codebehind the Controls property is provided.

Comment: then what should i do now... pleaseee

Comment: @HanyaIdrees These constructs will only work within asp.net (without too much hacking and pain).

Answer (score 0):

use **LITERAL CONTROL**

**HTML**
(example)

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server"> </asp:Panel>
```

**C#**

//And create the style as you want

```
panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div style='color: gray; height: 20px; width: 300px;'>I was created using Code Behind</div>"));
```

Comment: this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("")); i have used this syntax you provided, but this is giving an error that invalid argument. Is there a namespace requird for using this control

Comment: i am using a split container, on whose i add the control literalcontrol but this also gives the same error splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div></div>"));

Comment: so what you want to use is not this. You can't put divs in split containers, this code we gave is for asp.net.

Comment: maybe what you want to use is a panel not a div

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps:
[Adding panels to SplitContainer in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452600/adding-panels-to-splitcontainer-in-windows-forms)

```
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    Label lbl = new Label();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        panel.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        panel.Height = 20;
        panel.Width = 300;
        lbl.Text = "I was created using Code Behind";
        panel.Controls.Add(lbl);

        dynDiv.Panel1.Controls.Add(panel);
    }
```

for what you say this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

I made as **Diogo Severiano** said and it worked.

In my case I needed to add controls to a div and I could not use a literal control because intellisense marks: "**controls cannot be added to a literal control**".

If that is the case do as he did.

`Label lblParaname = new Label();
    lblParaname.Text = Record.Parameter_Name + ": ";
    lblParaname.ID = "lbl" + Record.Parameter_Name;
    lblParaname.EnableViewState = true;
    lblParaname.Attributes.Add("cssclass", "grid_3 alpha omega");
    Panel pLblContainer = new Panel();
    pLblContainer.CssClass = "grid_3";
    pLblContainer.Controls.Add(lblParaname);
    pSubsPar.Controls.Add(pLblContainer);`